# response undefined using then for async redux api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to properly redirect user using the response of the api call in redux? I need the resp after axios's then but I got undefined, although I've returned the thunk in my action

```
//jobForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createJob } from '~/actions/jobAction'

import { getUserId } from '~/utils'
import moment from 'moment'

@connect(state=>state.job,{createJob})
class Form extends Component {

  handleSubmitForm = () => {
    this.props.createJob({formData})
    .then(resp => console.log(resp)) //undefined?)
  }

  //etc..
}

export default Form

//action

export function createJob(params) {
  return dispatch=>{

    dispatch({type: CREATING_JOB})

    return axios.post(`/job/create`, {...params})
    .then(res=>{
      if(res.status===200 && res.data.status===1){
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_JOB,
          payload: res.data.data
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(res => {
      dispatch(errorMsg(res.data.msg))
    })
  }
}
```

I can pass my payload to reducer but I need a response's id to redirect the user to a created job page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything after processing the API call, which is why the promise resolves to "undefined". For the promise to resolve with data, you'll need to return the id after dispatching the action. See below.

```
export function createJob(params) {
  return dispatch=>{

    dispatch({type: CREATING_JOB})

    return axios.post(`/job/create`, {...params})
    .then(res=>{
      if(res.status===200 && res.data.status===1){
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_JOB,
          payload: res.data.data
        });

        // RETURN ID AFTER DISPATCHING ACTION
        return res.data.data

      }
    })
    .catch(res => {
      dispatch(errorMsg(res.data.msg))
    })
  }
}
```

An alternative approach, that is arguably more inline with the flux one-way data flow paradigm would be to perform the redirect based on a change in the redux state rather than completion of the action.

You could use componentWillReceiveProps to determine if the new job has been created, if so, redirect

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  // use nextProps to determine if the new job has been added
  // to the job state
  // ...
  const isNewJobAdded = nextProps.job.includes(...)
  if (isNewJobAdded) {
    // perform redirect
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: let me try, but is this the way to do it in redux? is it proper to use chaining in api in the view?

Comment: a more idiomatic way to do this in redux would respect the one-way data flow, and have the component subscribe to changes in the reducer, which results in an update of the component, which would then perform the page redirect. you'd need to add a fair bit of code to do that.

Comment: I thought when u use redux, you rarely how to use the lifecycle method anymore?

Comment: Not necessarily. Container components will always need some lifecylce hooks to connect to dispatch actions to redux stores.

Comment: why need componentWillReceiveProps when you can access this.props.job if u use redux?

Comment: If all you need to do is render the job, then you don't need to hook into componentWillReceiveProps. As you need to perform a redirect, you'll need to do that outside of the render method, and componentWillReceiveProps is the earliest point at which you have sufficient information to determine if a redirect is required. Unless you are using ReactRouter4, in which you could just use the <Redirect /> component to perform the redirect.